# Python dataframe drop rows with only index no cell values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an interesting situation. My imported dataframe has index values but no cell values.
This causing error from carrying any functions. How to delete those rows which have only index but no cell values.

My present dataframe:

```
df = 
        Time      A        B        C
1    5/7/2020 7:27  17.75613834  37.63067245  0.292461243
2    5/7/2020 7:28  17.81356335  38.32342911   0.30196029
3    5/7/2020 7:29  17.85858633  39.14722824  0.309710972
4    5/7/2020 7:30  17.80791306  39.10982895  0.317052315
5                                                      
6                                                     
7
```

In the above, how do I delete 5, 6, 7 rows? My original dataframe has many rows. But I do not know which rows have index values but are empty. I wanted something automatic.
I tried following but it did not work.

```
#### Dropt rows withs empty cells
df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
df.dropna(how='all',inplace=True)
```

Comment: Is `index` actually a column, or the index? Do you actually get `NaN`s after doing the replace?

Comment: @CeliusStingher I simply imported a `CSV` file. This is how it looks like. I am not getting any `NaN`s after the replacement.

Comment: `df[df['index'] <5]`? Also, it might be worth tuning the import, rather than correcting a suboptimally imported dataframe.

Comment: @warped I am sure this works in this case. But in a general case, where we do not know which row causing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['Time', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    data=[['5/7/2020 7:27', '17.75613834', '37.63067245', '0.292461243'],
          ['5/7/2020 7:28', '17.81356335', '38.32342911', ' 0.30196029'],
          ['5/7/2020 7:29', '17.85858633', '39.14722824', '0.309710972'],
          ['5/7/2020 7:30', '17.80791306', '39.10982895', '0.317052315'],
          ['', '', '', '']]
)

df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
df = df.dropna()
```

Returns

```
            Time            A            B            C
0  5/7/2020 7:27  17.75613834  37.63067245  0.292461243
1  5/7/2020 7:28  17.81356335  38.32342911   0.30196029
2  5/7/2020 7:29  17.85858633  39.14722824  0.309710972
3  5/7/2020 7:30  17.80791306  39.10982895  0.317052315
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['Time', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    data=[['5/7/2020 7:27', '17.75613834', '37.63067245', '0.292461243'],
          ['5/7/2020 7:28', '17.81356335', '38.32342911', ' 0.30196029'],
          ['5/7/2020 7:29', '17.85858633', '39.14722824', '0.309710972'],
          ['5/7/2020 7:30', '17.80791306', '39.10982895', '0.317052315'],
          ['', '', '', ''],
           ['', '', '', ''],
            ['', '', '', ''],
          ['5/7/2020 7:27', '17.75613834', '37.63067245', '0.292461243']])
df=df[df!= ''].dropna()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
original df:
            Time            A            B            C
0  5/7/2020 7:27  17.75613834  37.63067245  0.292461243
1  5/7/2020 7:28  17.81356335  38.32342911   0.30196029
2  5/7/2020 7:29  17.85858633  39.14722824  0.309710972
3  5/7/2020 7:30  17.80791306  39.10982895  0.317052315
4                                                      
5                                                      
6                                                      
7  5/7/2020 7:27  17.75613834  37.63067245  0.292461243


newdf:

            Time            A            B            C
0  5/7/2020 7:27  17.75613834  37.63067245  0.292461243
1  5/7/2020 7:28  17.81356335  38.32342911   0.30196029
2  5/7/2020 7:29  17.85858633  39.14722824  0.309710972
3  5/7/2020 7:30  17.80791306  39.10982895  0.317052315
7  5/7/2020 7:27  17.75613834  37.63067245  0.292461243
```